# What are the impacts of using Object.class lock in synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, locking

I am trying to synchronize read write operations on xml file from multiple methods in multiple classes. To achieve this, I am synchronizing this operations by using class level lock.

Code sample:

Test1.java:

```
public class Test1 {

    public void method1() {

        synchronized(CommonUtility.class) {
            SomeObject someObject = testDAO.readSomething();
            .
            .
            .
            testDAO.writeSomething(someObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Test2.java

```
public class Test2 {

    public void method2() {

        synchronized(CommonUtility.class) {
            SomeObject someObject = testDAO.readSomething();
            .
            .
            .
            testDAO.writeSomething(someObject);
        }
    }
}
```

To achieve this class level lock, consider following sample code:

```
synchronized(CommonUtility.class) {
  .
  .
  .
}
```

What are the impacts of using Object.class instead of CommonUtility.class, like:

```
synchronized(Object.class) {
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: The implication is that you are synchronizing on `Object.class`, which is almost certainly unnecessary, rather than `CommonUtiliity.class`, which may *also* be unnecessary as compared to synchronizing on an instance, depending on what happens inside the `synchronized` block. Don't reduce concurrency any more than is actually  necessary. This is rather basic. Unless your `CommonUtility.class` has `static` variables you only need to synchronize on an instance of it.

Comment: IMO, the idea of "class level" lock and "object level" lock is distracting. There is only _one_ underlying synchronization mechanism in Java: `synchronized (o) { ... }` where `o` can be any Java object (note: a class _is_ an object.) If you want to prevent two threads from accessing the same data at the same time, then make sure that the threads only access the data after locking the same object. It doesn't need to be any more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0):

I think both approaches aren't ideal.

First of all, this [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) suggests:

> You might wonder what happens when a static synchronized method is invoked, since a static method is associated with a class, not an object. In this case, the thread acquires the intrinsic lock for the Class object associated with the class.

In other words: when you use `synchronized(CommonUtility.class)` you **implicitly** get "synchronized" with all static `synchronized` methods within CommonUtility. And worse: imagine that class has no such methods today. But next week, someone adds such a static `synchronized` method in that utility class, assuming that only calls to that method go through that monitor. Worst case, that could lead to some ugly (runtime only) surprises.

Then: going for even broader scope (by using Object.class) makes things worse.

My answer: avoid using class objects in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the idea of "class level" lock and "object level" lock is distracting. There is only one underlying synchronization mechanism in Java: `synchronized (o) { ... }` where `o` can be any Java object (Note that in Java `MyClass.class` *is* an object.)

When you write,

```
synchronized SomeType foobar(...) { ... }
```

That's really just a shortcut way of using an instance as the lock object that protects its own member variables.

```
SomeType foobar(...) {
    synchronized (this) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Same goes for so-called "class level" locking: It's just a shorthand way of using the class itself as the lock object that protects its own static members.

---

Speaking of which...

Good practice keeps the lock object near the data that it protects (for some definition of "near"). If the data are `private`, then the lock object ought to be `private`. If the data are members of some instance, then the lock object ought to be members of the same instance, etc.

`Object.class` isn't particularly "near" anything. It will *work* as well as any other object, but using it makes your code harder to understand, because the reader will spend time wondering what motivated you to choose `Object.class`, and wondering whether your choice was based on a misunderstanding.

My own preference, for protecting instance members, looks like this:

```
class MyClass {
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private SomeType someVariableThatNeedsProtection = ...;
    private SomeOtherType someOtherVariableThatAlsoNeedsProtection...;
    ...
    public ... foobar(...) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And, If I need to protect `static` members:

```
...
private static final Object lock = new Object();
...
```

The `lock` variable is `private`, just like the data it protects. Nobody who wants to understand your code will need to spend any time searching for anything else that is protected by the same lock object because they know it can't be accessed from outside of the `MyClass` methods.

The `lock` variable also is `final`. That will save readers from having to examine your code to make sure that it's always  the *same* object that gets used as the lock. (Hint: if you think you need to be able to assign the `lock` variable, then you are either doing something that's sophisticated beyond the comfort level of many programmers, or you are making a bad mistake.)

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to synchronize read write operations on XML file from multiple methods in multiple classes. To achieve this, I am synchronizing this operation by using class level lock.

That is not a good idea.  You should have a single class (maybe `XmlHelper`) which manages the XML file and does the locking.  `XmlHelper` would be used in the multiple methods in multiple classes and would control the locking on the file instead of multiple classes having to worry about it.  That's much better object design.

Maybe something like:

```
public class XmlHelper {
    public XmlHelper(File xmlFile) {
    public synchronized SomeObject readSomething() { ... }
    public synchronized void writeSomething(SomeObject someObject) { ... }
}
```

Then your `Test1` and `Test2` classes must share the same instance of the `XmlHelper` class so their locks will block each other.  Instance level locks aren't always a great idea again because locks should be as fine-grained as possible, but it is fine in your application since the `XmlHelper` is designed for multiple classes to lock their IO operations.

> What are the impacts of using `Object.class` instead of `CommonUtility.class`, like:

As others have mentioned, locking on the class is the same as calling a `synchronized static` method.  This pattern should be used very sparingly since the lock is so coarse grained.  What if your program needed to read/write to 2 XML files at the same time?  Your class level lock would cause IO operations to the 2 files block each other -- not optimal.

If you locked on `Object.class` then any other class which happens to be doing the same lock will block your threads unnecessarily.  God help you.

> A race condition is getting hit.  For example: thread1 reads file contents and updates read contents. Before thread1 writes back to file, thread2 reads content. Then thread1 writes updated contents to file. And at last thread2 writes content to file. This is leading to contents loss,

There are a couple of ways of doing this.  You could have some sort of update method on your `XmlHelper` class:

```
public synchronized void updateObject(...) {
   SomeObjecto obj = readSomething();
   // adjust object here based on the arguments
   writeSomething(obj);
}
```

If each of the threads need to do their own updating then they will need to lock externally on the same object.  I recommend locking on the shared instance of the `XmlHelper`.

```
synchronized (xmlHelper) {
     ...
}
```

The locking on the class object will work but it is far to big a hammer to be recommended.  Again, if you have 2 instances of the `XmlHelper` working on 2 different files, you would not want IO operations on 2 different files to block each other.

Comment: read and write methods are already synchronized. But race condition is getting hit, like: thread1 reads files content and update read contents. Before thread1 writes back to file, thread2 reads content. Then thread1 writes updated contents to file. And at last thread2 writes content to file. This is leading to contents loss, updated by thread1. That is why trying "to synchronize this read write operations in 1 block using class level lock across multiple java classes in different packages".

Comment: I've updated my answer @Hrushikesh to take into account this new info.